# how to update large information in excel to oracle database using jsp or servlet or java

Tags: java, jsp

in my project i have a excel sheet which contains the marks,id,credits in large number... i need to upload into database from excel file.... iam using apache poi to read and update but iam getting error...

**DB_Connection.java**

```
      package DB;
      import java.sql.*;
      import java.sql.Connection;
      import java.sql.DriverManager;
      import java.sql.SQLException;
      public class DB_Connection 
      {
                // private String datasize;
                    private Connection con;
                 public DB_Connection()
                 {


                     try
                {
                            String conUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
                           String userName="SYSTEM";
                            String pass="raje";
                           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                               con=DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,userName,pass);
                }
                catch(Exception s)
                {
                       System.out.println(s);
                }


             }
          public Connection getConn()
            {
               return con;
            }
         public void setConn(Connection con)
          {
                 this.con = con;
          }

        }
```

**readExcel.jsp:**

```
      <%@page  language="java" import="java.sql.*"  contentType="text/html"   pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
      <!DOCTYPE html>

       <%@ page import ="java.util.Date" %>
       <%@ page import ="java.io.*" %>
       <%@ page import ="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>
       <%@ page import ="java.io.IOException" %>
       <%@ page import ="java.util.Iterator" %>
       <%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %>
       <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell" %>
       <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow" %>
       <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet" %>
       <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" %>
       <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" %>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <jsp:useBean id="connection" class="DB.DB_Connection" scope="application">
        <jsp:setProperty name="connection" property="*"/>

       </jsp:useBean> 

        <%!     
           Connection con;
           PreparedStatement ps=null;

         public static ArrayList readExcelFile(String fileName)
          {
    /** --Define a ArrayList
        --Holds ArrayList Of Cells
     */

    ArrayList cellArrayListHolder = new ArrayList();

    try{
    /** Creating Input Stream**/
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
       // System.out.print("myInput");


    /** Create a POIFSFileSystem object**/
    POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

    /** Create a workbook using the File System**/
     HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

     /** Get the first sheet from workbook**/
    HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

    /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
      Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
      while(rowIter.hasNext())
      {
          HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
          Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
          ArrayList cellStoreArrayList=new ArrayList();
          while(cellIter.hasNext())
          {
              HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();                   
              cellStoreArrayList.add(myCell);
          }

          cellArrayListHolder.add(cellStoreArrayList);
      }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    return cellArrayListHolder;

       }%>


     <%
        String fileName="C://Documents and Settings//raje//Desktop//JGRESULTS1.xls"; 
            ArrayList dataHolder=readExcelFile(fileName);
        //Print the data read
       //printCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);
         con= connection.getConn();
          ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into sample2 values(?,?,?,?)");
              int count=1;
         ArrayList cellStoreArrayList=null;
        //For inserting into database
         for (int i=1;i < dataHolder.size(); i++)
          {
              cellStoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(i);
       ps.setString(1,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString());
       ps.setString(2,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString());
       ps.setString(3,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString());
       ps.setString(4,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(3)).toString()); 
      count= ps.executeUpdate();
       System.out.print(((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(3)).toString() + "\t");
       }
               count++;
         //For checking data is inserted or not?
           if(count>0)
        { %>
               Following details from Excel file have been inserted in student table of database
                   <table>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Student's Name</th>
                           <th>Class</th>
                           <th>external</th>
                           <th>credits</th>
                       </tr>

        <% for (int i=1;i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
              cell StoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(i);%>
           <tr>
        <td><%=((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString() %></td>
        <td><%=((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString() %></td>
        <td><%=((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString() %></td>
        <td><%=((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(3)).toString() %></td>

            </tr>
       <%}
      }
              else
               {%>

             <%  out.print("not successfull"); 
             }    %> 
       </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**output:**

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /readExcel.jsp at line 98

95:     {
96:     cellStoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(i);
97:        ps.setString(1,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString());
98:        ps.setString(2,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString());
99:        ps.setString(3,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString());
100:        ps.setString(4,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(3)).toString()); 
101:       count= ps.executeUpdate();
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:553)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:3 93)
    root cause

         java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    org.apache.jsp.readExcel_jsp._jspService(readExcel_jsp.java:175)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get more and better help if you actually post the error.

This code is a mess.  It's doing too much:

1. POI to read and parse spreadsheets
2. JSP to display
3. JDBC to persist

I'd recommend decomposing it into pieces as separate classes that you can develop, test, and put aside.

No one should be writing JSPs with scriptlets.  That's a discredited 1999 style.  Better to learn JSTL and add some servlets.

UPDATE:

Here's the cause:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
```

You've assumed that an array element is present, but the JVM disagrees with you.

Here's the essence of what you did wrong:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
values.add("element one"); 
System.out.println(values.size());  // this will print 1
System.out.println(values.get(100)); // there's only one element in the list, but you tried to access 100.
```

Error!  Figure out where your code did something like this and you'll have it.

Comment: thank u i will try it using jstl. Sir but i dont understand this error, and how i can solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out: what you do is a very bad practice...

However, the current problem is most likely, that the row you are trying to read a cell from is not long enough, so the (note: array backed ) list runs out of bounds.

To be prepared for this situation, I'd do it this way:

```
   cellStoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(i);
   for(int i=1;i<4;i++) { // I'd use a loop even for fixed number of iterations, I vigorously hate duplication
       if(cellStoreArrayList.size()>=i) { // check for row to be long enough --> no ArrayOutOfBounds anymore               HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(i-1);
           if(cell!=null) { // check for null: no NullPointerException anymore...
               ps.setString(i,cell.toString());
           }
           else {
               ps.setString(i,"");
           }
           //ps.setString(i,cell==null?"":cell.toString()); //this is good too, but a bit probably less readable
       }
   }
```

**Notes**:

- use generics! the List could have had a  `<HSSFCell>` generic type, eliminating the need for a cast, and solving quite some possibilities for mistakes and errors
- don't store the name fo the implementation in the variable name! `cellStoreArrayList` = bad! `cellStoreList` = good

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code and the stack trace it looks like you are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the row of cells in the `cellStoreArrayList` is only of length 1. I would recommend looking at your spreadsheet to ensure that every row you are reading in has 4 columns since this constraint is hardcoded.

On a related note, if you are going to hardcode array indices you should surround it in some kind of exception catching mechanism.